# How to deal with a sealed class when I wanted to inherit and add properties

Tags: c#, .net

In a [recent question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955541/how-might-i-complete-this-example-using-linq-and-string-parsing), I asked how I might parse through a file name to extra meta info about a file.

After I worked through that problem, I decided that I might want to create new type of object to hold the meta data and the original file.  I thought I might do something like this:

```
class BackupFileInfo : FileInfo, IEquatable<BackupFileInfo>
{
    //Properties and Methods here
}
```

The idea would be that I would retain the original `FileInfo` object while adding meta information in the properties of the object that implements `FileInfo`, such as `IsMainBackup`.

**However, `FileInfo` is sealed, which means other classes cannot inherit from it.**

Instead, I ended up with the following:

```
class BackupFileInfo : IEquatable<BackupFileInfo>
{
    public bool IsMainBackup { get; set; }
    public int ImageNumber { get; set; }
    public int IncrementNumber { get; set; }
    public FileInfo FileInfo { get; set; }

    //public BackupFileInfo() //constructor here

    public bool Equals(BackupFileInfo other)
    {
        return (this.FileInfo.Name == other.FileInfo.Name
             && this.FileInfo.Length == other.FileInfo.Length);
    }

}
```

I'm not terribly excited about this solution because instead of being able to use `BackupFileInfo.Length`, I'm going to have to use `BackupFileInfo.FileInfo.Length`.  Perhaps this is the best practice already, but something doesn't feel right.

**Is there a better way to deal with this problem?**

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is one of the classic composition instead of inheritance examples and you went in the right direction.

To solve your property problem just create a property called `Length` that delegates to the encapsulated `FileInfo` object.

Comment: Exactly what I was about to write.

Comment: This is also named `Least Knowledge Principle`

Answer (score 16):

You could add an [implicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit) operator to your class.

Eg:

```
class BackupFileInfo .... {
  /* your exiting code */

  public static implicit operator FileInfo( BackupFileInfo self ){
     return self.FileInfo;
  }
}
```

You could then treat your BackupFileInfo object like a FileInfo object like so

```
BackupFileInfo bf = new BackupFileInfo();
...
int mylen = ((FileInfo)bf).Length;
```

Comment: so I would have to cast the `BackupFileInfo` as a `FileInfo` in order to access the properties and methods of `FileInfo`?  If that's the case, I think I'd rather just use `BackupFileInfo.FileInfo`.

Comment: doesn't solve the problem but +1 because it's really interesting!

Comment: link to implicit doc appears dead

Comment: @Jerther, the current documentation for the implicit operator can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit. I have a pending edit to update the link in the answer.

Comment: Did you mean `public static implicit` **`operator`** `FileInfo(BackupFileInfo self) { ...}` ?

Answer (score 11):

You could just expose the properties on FileInfo you care about. Something like this:

```
public long Length { get { return FileInfo.Length; } }
```

This obviously becomes less practical if you want to delegate a lot of properties to FileInfo.

Answer (score 6):

Pass-thru?

```
class BackupFileInfo : IEquatable<BackupFileInfo>
{
    public long Length {get {return FileInfo.Length;}}
    //.... [snip]
}
```

Also, a prop called `FileInfo` is asking for trouble... it may need disambiguation against the `FileInfo` class in a few places.

Comment: Good point about the `FileInfo` naming convention.  I was trying to avoid annoying myself with names like `MyFileInfo`, `ThisFileInfo`, `SuperFileInfo`.

Comment: Actually, giving a property the same name than its type (when it makes sense) is recommended over adding such prefixes and common enough in the BCL (SolidBrush.Color, for example). See Naming Guidelines at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzcth91k.aspx .

Answer (score 2):

You can easily wrap the file info properties in your own properties if you like.

```
public long Length
{
    get
    {
       return this.FileInfo.Length;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Length` is `long`, not `int`

Comment: fixed, it was a guess really!

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't really solve your larger problem, but of course you can just make the properties you want to use act as proxies to the real properties underneath.  E.g.

```
public long Length
{
    get {return FileInfo.Length;}
}
```

(With approriate null-checking of course.)