# How to name a property when the preferred name is also the name of the type

Tags: c#, .net, properties, naming-conventions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Giving a property the same name as its class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095644/giving-a-property-the-same-name-as-its-class)

In [working on a solution where I was struggling to "add" properties to a sealed class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023769/how-to-deal-with-a-sealed-class-when-i-wanted-to-inherit-and-add-properties), someone pointed out that [my naming of a property with the same name as a type was asking for trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023769/how-to-deal-with-a-sealed-class-when-i-wanted-to-inherit-and-add-properties/2023799#2023799).

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
class BackupFileInfo : IEquatable<BackupFileInfo>
{
    public FileInfo FileInfo { get; set; }
}
```

I would have preferred to just inherit `FileInfo`, but I can't since it's sealed.  I'd also like to name it `FileInfo` (since that's exactly what it is), but want to avoid potential problems later on.  I'm trying to avoid silly names like `MyFileInfo`, but I'm stumped at how best to name the property of type `FileInfo`.

**Is there a best practice for naming properties in this situation?**

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095644/giving-a-property-the-same-name-as-its-class.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the duplicate! That's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, it's unavoidable.

But in this case, I would name that property 'File'. I never actually have this situation come up in my own projects, but in some others I've worked on I've seen it, and it's not the end of the world (and obviously, it's valid).