# Computer name from ServerManager Site and ApplicationPool

Tags: c#, powershell

I am writing some PowerShell cmdlets in C# to access our production servers and report on the IIS/Service state.

The `ServiceController` class has a `MachineName` property, but neither `Site` nor `ApplicationPool` classes have this.

How would I go about returning the computer name alongside these objects (i.e. `Get-Service | select MachineName,Status,DisplayName`)? I considered extending the classes, but they are sealed and I don't wish to spend time implementing [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023769/how-to-deal-with-a-sealed-class-when-i-wanted-to-inherit-and-add-properties).

Does anyone with more skill in writing cmdlets have an idea how I can easily accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply wrote a small wrapper for the classes I wanted. It's not perfect but it's also not important enough to spend time on.

```
public class MyApplicationPool
{
    public MyApplicationPool(ApplicationPool appPool, string machineName)
    {
        Name = appPool.Name;
        MachineName = machineName;
        State = appPool.State;
        Cpu = appPool.Cpu;
        QueueLength = appPool.QueueLength;

        ApplicationPool = appPool;
    }

    public string MachineName { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public ObjectState State { get; }
    public long QueueLength { get; }
    public ApplicationPoolCpu Cpu { get; }

    public ObjectState Start()
    {
        return ApplicationPool.Start();
    }

    public ObjectState Stop()
    {
        return ApplicationPool.Stop();
    }

    public ObjectState Recycle()
    {
        return ApplicationPool.Recycle();
    }

    private ApplicationPool ApplicationPool { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom expression with the `Select` cmdlet to add an custom property to the object that is returned by it.

```
$mn = $env:COMPUTERNAME
Get-Service | Select @{Expression={$mn};Label="MachineName"},Status,DisplayName
```

For more information on custom expression see this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692794.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, that is a useful tip for PowerShell. Any idea how to accomplish it in C#? I might attempt to use a dynamic object.